# Sum Of Two Queries HQL

Tags: hql, sum

I have two tables, Ticket and Job, and both have a ClientId field and a TimeSpent field.

I'm using HQL and can get the sum of TimeSpent from one table but I don't know how to get it from multiple tables as HQL has no `UNION`.

This is what I'm using at the moment:

```
SELECT SUM(j.TimeSpent) FROM Job j WHERE j.ClientId = :clientId
```

Comment: Is there any reason you can't do two queries and add the results together?

Comment: Trying to keep it all neatly in one query. It's a section of a larger query

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just want to add up both sets of times. You should be able to use this as an expression in a larger query:

```
       (SELECT SUM(j.TimeSpent) FROM Job j WHERE j.ClientId = :clientId)
     + (SELECT SUM(t.TimeSpent) FROM Ticket t WHERE t.ClientId = :clientId)
```

Comment: The problem when I try that is I get a `DOT node with no left-hand-side!` error. Any idea how to remedy that?

Comment: @Harold: You should post a complete query and complete error message.